# How to exit terminal with one command when running as root?

Tags: terminal, root

I know that I can quit the terminal using the `exit` command when I'm running the terminal as the normal user. By normal I mean the default user that gets created when a linux distribution gets installed. But when I change from current user to root, if I try to exit the terminal, I have to execute the `exit` command twice. The first one to exit the root user, the second one to quit the terminal. Is there any command to quit the terminal regardless of which user is using it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't mention how you change users.  I'll assume `sudo` -- it could be something else (e.g., `su`).

If you want the non-root user's shell to terminate when the `sudo` terminates (when you type `exit` as root), you can do:

```bsh
$ exec sudo -i
```

Here the `exec` replaces the user's shell process with the new command (here, `sudo`).  When you type `exit` as root, `sudo` will terminate.  Since the `exec` replaced the user's shell process with `sudo`, then there's no user shell to which to return.